# Disable eclipse warnings on javadoc-less private fields

Tags: eclipse, warnings, field, javadoc, private

I set up my javadoc options on eclipse to put missing javadoc warnings for everything private and above (so everything). This is *almost* what I want. Is there a way for it to not warn on private fields? Private functions and classes should still generate warnings if they have no javadocs, but fields should not.